# Photoshop. Can i make "linked" the default method for dragging new artwork into documents?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, designers, cc-2015

So far photoshop threat artwork that you into your document as new smart objects. I would like to get mor used to using "linked" as opposed to embedded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this the default, however you can hold the **alt** key while importing your layer and it will become a linked smart object instead of a regular one.